# Create JSON from PHP to datatables

Tags: php, json

Hi guys im having some trouble creating the json i need to send to my datatable JS.
I see that in my output i get the ''keys'' inside the array and in the one that i need i dont get them.
How can i creat an array without those keys or i dont need an array inside another array? So this is the output of the JSON that i need:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "DT_RowId": "row_1",
            "first_name": "Tiger",
            "last_name": "Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "email": "t.nixon@datatables.net",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": 5421,
            "age": 61,
            "salary": 20800,
            "start_date": "2011-04-25"
        },
        {
            "DT_RowId": "row_1",
            "first_name": "Tiger",
            "last_name": "Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "email": "t.nixon@datatables.net",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": 5421,
            "age": 61,
            "salary": 20800,
            "start_date": "2011-04-25"
        }
    ]
}
```

what i have is this:

```
$json = array(
        'Data' => array(
                '1' => array(
                        "DT_RowId" => "row_1",
                        "first_name"=> "Tiger",
                        "last_name"=>  "Nixon",
                        "position"=>  "System Architect",
                        "email"=>  "t.nixon@datatables.net",
                        "office"=>  "Edinburgh",
                        "extn"=>  5421,
                        "age"=>  61,
                        "salary"=>  20800,
                        "start_date"=>  "2011-04-25"
                ),
                '2' => array(
                        "DT_RowId" => "row_1",
                        "first_name"=> "Tiger",
                        "last_name"=>  "Nixon",
                        "position"=>  "System Architect",
                        "email"=>  "t.nixon@datatables.net",
                        "office"=>  "Edinburgh",
                        "extn" =>  5421,
                        "age"=>  61,
                        "salary"=>  20800,
                        "start_date"=>  "2011-04-25"
            ),
));
echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and the output is:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "1": {
            "DT_RowId": "row_1",
            "first_name": "Tiger",
            "last_name": "Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "email": "t.nixon@datatables.net",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": 5421,
            "age": 61,
            "salary": 20800,
            "start_date": "2011-04-25"
        },
        "2": {
            "DT_RowId": "row_1",
            "first_name": "Tiger",
            "last_name": "Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "email": "t.nixon@datatables.net",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": 5421,
            "age": 61,
            "salary": 20800,
            "start_date": "2011-04-25"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about not using an associative array in the PHP to begin with?

Comment: well i need to create that array from a foreach. You have sugestion how to do it?

Comment: A foreach of what? We have no idea what the original source data is

Comment: data is coming from server. Need to run a foreach from the result of the query and creat that json or creat an array and then encode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i messed around and i finally got it to work.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "datatables_demo");

$q = 'SELECT * FROM datatables_demo';
$result = $mysqli->query($q);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $resultarray[] = $row;
}

$data = array();
    foreach ($resultarray as $info)
    {
        array_push($data, $info);
    }

$json = array(
    'data' => $data
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

And teh result output as expected:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "1",
        "first_name": "jhon",
        "last_name": "grcfsdia",
        "position": "ceo",
        "email": "wwfe@fdsf.vom",
        "office": "aenbx",
        "extn": "23",
        "age": "422",
        "salary": "19999.00",
        "start_date": "05-01-1490"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "first_name": "srte",
        "last_name": "gabdr",
        "position": "ceASFo",
        "email": "wwfe@ASDfdsf.vom",
        "office": "aawwwa",
        "extn": "2343",
        "age": "422",
        "salary": "19999.00",
        "start_date": "15-11-1911"
    }]
}
```